# Automatic Build for Non-Java Eclipse Project

Tags: eclipse, ant, build-automation

I have a project that contains xml files.  I also have an Ant build in that project to generate documentation based on the xml files. The Ant build calls a Ruby script for generation.

I would like a way run that Ant build after the modification of any resource in the "{project}/xml" folder. I know that I can right click on the build.xml and Run As->Ant Build, but I want it to be more like the incremental build for Java projects.  I have tried creating a builder, importing the Ant build and setting up relevant resources, but when I make a change to the XML file, a build does not start.  I have "Build Automatically" checked for the project as well.

This must be possible.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom builder will only run when a file is saved that is in a source directory. Make sure the `/xml` folder is included as a source location in the Project Properties, Java Build Path.

Comment: Looks like that was my problem.  I figured setting it as a "relevant resource" would have done it.  Thanks!